# This spring send json got 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've tried for awhile, how come this thing does not get a response?   It always couldn't find the url mapping/404 not found.
I am trying to send json request to localhost/test and wish I could get any response, but invain.

This is my **web.xml** file

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >        
  <web-app>
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>    
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

This is the dispather-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring- beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean name="test" class="com.my.controller.TestController"></bean>     

</beans>
```

This is the TestController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {
@RequestMapping(value = {"/test"}, headers =   "Accept=application/json")
    public String getBid(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test...");
        return "is itworking?!";
    }     
}
```

Comment: Please share the URL that you are invoking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You should return from getBid(...) logic name of view ("test") - don't return sample string like this -> "is itworking?!". Another solution is use @ResponseBody to JSON - [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Spring will not understand that `TestController` is a controller unless you have `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your config, otherwise you need `@ResponseBody` to skip the View resolvers

Comment: I added it, now I can only get the RequestBody via POST method and pass the body string to /test, but when I use GET method, the body is empty, is there a way to pass the body string in /test with GET? which method could I return a json string back to the request?